# If cookie exists, don't run the JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

I've got this code that shows an annoying ext intent overlay when going to the back button, but I don't want it to show up if a specific cookie exists. This is the cookie my exit button makes.

**JavaScript:**

```
function dontshow(){       
    days=30;
    myDate = new Date();
    myDate.setTime(myDate.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));    
    document.cookie = 'dontshow=OK; expires=' + myDate.toGMTString();     
}
```

This is the code which shows my exit intent overlay.

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    canRun = false;
    waitPeriod = 1000;// waiting time
    setTimeout(function() { canRun = true; }, waitPeriod);     

    $(document).on("mouseleave", function (event) {
        if (!canRun) {
            return false;
        }
        if (event.pageY < 0) {
            $(".leavemodal").fadeIn(600);
        }
    });
});
```

I want to make an if and else statement saying: **If the cookie "dontshow" exists, don't run the code for my exit intent overlay.** I've tried some stuff but it's not working. Does anyone have any ideas on how to get it to work.

Comment: `if (document.cookie.indexOf('dontshow=OK') > -1)` would this not work?

Comment: it works, thanks man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check if there substring in cookie string by [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) method.

```
if (document.cookie.indexOf("dontshow=OK") != -1) ...
```