# Check if cookie exist in a javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, cookies

I have the following JavaScript on my `rails app` and I want to run it only when the cookie doesn't exist.

```
function getGeoLocation() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(setGeoCookie);
}

function setGeoCookie(position) {
    var cookie_val = position.coords.latitude + "|" + position.coords.longitude;
    document.cookie = "lat_lng=" + escape(cookie_val);
}
```

I'm using this to call the script on my rails app:

```
 <%- unless @lat_lng %>
        <script>
            getGeoLocation();
        </script>
  <%- end %>
```

**Update**

I updated my `application.js` file according to @Njdhv answer and the popup still appears. Here is what I did:

```
function getCookieByName(name) {
var parts = document.cookie.split('; '),
    len = parts.length,
    item, i, ret;
for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    item = parts[i].split('=');
    if (item[0] === name) {
        ret = item[1];
        return ret ? unescape(ret) : '';
    }
    }
 return null;
}

if(getCookieByName('lat_lng') != null){
    console.log('lat_lng')
    function getGeoLocation() {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(setGeoCookie);
    }

    function setGeoCookie(position) {
        var cookie_val = position.coords.latitude + "|" + position.coords.longitude;
       document.cookie = "lat_lng=" + escape(cookie_val);
    }
}else{
//you can put your logic here...
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If cookie exists, don't run the JavaScript code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39365279/if-cookie-exists-dont-run-the-javascript-code)

Answer (score 2):

I found out what was the problem, I had to change this inside my view:

from this:

```
 <%- unless @lat_lng %>
    <script>
        getGeoLocation();
    </script>
<%- end %>
```

to this:

```
<% if cookies[:lat_lng].nil? %>
    <script>
        getGeoLocation();
    </script>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have more than one cookie saved your searching cookie may not be the first ccokie in the cookie array you have to search for "lat_lng" and " lat_lng" both.

```
    var lat_lng;

        if (navigator.cookieEnabled) {
          cookieArray = document.cookie.split(";");
          cookieArray.forEach(myFunction);

          console.log(cookieArray)

          function myFunction(item, index) {
            if (item.split("=")[0] == " lat_lng" || item.split("=")[0] == "lat_lng") {
              lat_lng = item.split("=")[1];
              console.log("lat_lng " + lat_lng)
            }
          }
        }

if(lat_lng == null){

  //what you want to happen

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Nisal Edu... I added my code after the `if(lat_lng == null){` and the pop up is still appearing. I forgot to mention that I'm using it in a rails app. Also I updated my question with more info, if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can Read all cookies using [`document.cookie`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) accessible from curent location.

As per your requirement as you need `read` and `write` cookie in your `application` so you can create your own [Singleton](http://www.dofactory.com/javascript/singleton-design-pattern)
 for cockie `get` , `set` and `clear`(remove).

The **Singleton** Pattern limits the number of instances of a particular object to just one. This single instance is called the singleton.

Here below I have create an **Singleton** name is `cookieUtility`

```
var cookieUtility = (function() {
    return {
        /**
         * Creates a cookie with the specified name and value. Additional settings for the cookie may be optionally specified
         * (for example: expiration, access restriction, SSL).
         * @param {String} name The name of the cookie to set.
         * @param {Object} value The value to set for the cookie.
         * @param {Object} [expires] Specify an expiration date the cookie is to persist until. Note that the specified Date
         * object will be converted to Greenwich Mean Time (GMT).
         * @param {String} [path] Setting a path on the cookie restricts access to pages that match that path. Defaults to all
         * pages ('/').
         * @param {String} [domain] Setting a domain restricts access to pages on a given domain (typically used to allow
         * cookie access across subdomains). For example, "sencha.com" will create a cookie that can be accessed from any
         * subdomain of sencha.com, including www.sencha.com, support.sencha.com, etc.
         * @param {Boolean} [secure] Specify true to indicate that the cookie should only be accessible via SSL on a page
         * using the HTTPS protocol. Defaults to false. Note that this will only work if the page calling this code uses the
         * HTTPS protocol, otherwise the cookie will be created with default options.
         */
        set: function(name, value) {
            var argv = arguments,
                argc = arguments.length,
                expires = (argc > 2) ? argv[2] : null,
                path = (argc > 3) ? argv[3] : '/',
                domain = (argc > 4) ? argv[4] : null,
                secure = (argc > 5) ? argv[5] : false;
            document.cookie = name + "=" + escape(value) + ((expires === null) ? "" : ("; expires=" + expires.toUTCString())) + ((path === null) ? "" : ("; path=" + path)) + ((domain === null) ? "" : ("; domain=" + domain)) + ((secure === true) ? "; secure" : "");
        },
        /**
         * Retrieves cookies that are accessible by the current page. If a cookie does not exist, `get()` returns null. The
         * following example retrieves the cookie called "valid" and stores the String value in the variable validStatus.
         *
         *
         * @param {String} name The name of the cookie to get
         * @return {Object} Returns the cookie value for the specified name;
         * null if the cookie name does not exist.
         */
        get: function(name) {
            var parts = document.cookie.split('; '),
                len = parts.length,
                item, i, ret;
            // In modern browsers, a cookie with an empty string will be stored:
            // MyName=
            // In older versions of IE, it will be stored as:
            // MyName
            // So here we iterate over all the parts in an attempt to match the key.
            for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
                item = parts[i].split('=');
                if (item[0] === name) {
                    ret = item[1];
                    return ret ? unescape(ret) : '';
                }
            }
            return null;
        },
        /**
         * Removes a cookie with the provided name from the browser
         * if found by setting its expiration date to sometime in the past.
         * @param {String} name The name of the cookie to remove
         * @param {String} [path] The path for the cookie.
         * This must be included if you included a path while setting the cookie.
         */
        clear: function(name, path) {
            if (this.get(name)) {
                path = path || '/';
                document.cookie = name + '=' + '; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=' + path;
            }
        }
    }
})();
```

> How to use it ?

**1)** for getting cookie

```
cookieUtility.get('name')//need to pass cookie name
```

**2)** for setting cookie

```
cookieUtility.set('name','value')//need to pass cookie name and value of cookie
```

**3)** for remove cookie

```
cookieUtility.clear('name') //need to pass cookie name and path(if required)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Njdhv, please check my question for the update of what I did..

Comment: @Theopap please check my answer I have updated with [`Singleton`](http://www.dofactory.com/javascript/singleton-design-pattern). As I have seen in your question you are also want to `write` cookie so I hope this will help you much.

Answer (score -1):

The documentation of javascript explains this very well.

With `document.cookie` you can check if an cookie exists.
simply combining this with an `if` statement would look something like this:

```
if (document.cookie == null) {
// do nothing
}
else {
// run it!
}
```

Comment: If this is not the answer you are looking for, can you clarify a bit better what your actual problem is?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @John Does... I have updated the question with more info. I don't want the geolocation popup to appear if the cookie already exist.